# Turn any 2D image into 3D printable sculpture with code

Tags: python, c, image, image-processing, 3d

I'm trying to convert a 2D image into a 3D printable sculpture using just code. First I would like to know if it can be done with just a script? I already know Python and C and would be great of course if I could use one of these to do what I want.

Here are two links for you to see what I mean by saying "Turn any 2D image into 3D printable sculpture" (but these are using software):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngZwibfaysc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fe2zxcKSic

To be more specific I want to insert an image and just wait to get the result which will be a 3D sculpture.

Comment: you'd have to approximate a height map; you could do this with gimp-cli I think so no need to write a python script

Comment: 1. be more specific you want the real model or just the illumination encoded surface (and in which form...). 2. what kind of images you will use as input (universal is not doable/practical/reliable in CV/DIP). btw after seen the vids the C/C++ should not be too hard ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

was curious a bit so I encoded a small example of illumination surface encoding

- for each pixel of input image `height = (color_intensity)*scale`

**This is input image I tested with** (first nice Oil painting in Google search)**:**

[image: input]

**This is the result (point cloud 3D preview)**

[image: output] [image: output]

On the left is animated gif so reload/refresh page to see the animation if it is already stopped or download the gif and open in something more decend then brownser for gif preview... On the right is colored point cloud preview (static image)

**This is the C++ code for computing this:**

```
OpenGLtexture zed,nx,ny,nz; // height map,normal maps (just 2D images)
picture pic;                // source image

int x,y,a;
// resize textures to source image size
zed.resize(pic.xs,pic.ys); 
 nx.resize(pic.xs,pic.ys); float *pnx=(float*) nx.txr;
 ny.resize(pic.xs,pic.ys); float *pny=(float*) ny.txr;
 nz.resize(pic.xs,pic.ys); float *pnz=(float*) nz.txr;
// prepare tmp image for height map extraction
picture pic0;
pic0=pic;       // copy
pic0.rgb2i();   // grayscale

// this computes the point cloud (this is the only important stuff from this code)
// as you can see there are just 3 lines of code important from all of this
for (a=0,y=0;y<pic.ys;y++)
 for (x=0;x<pic.xs;x++,a++)
  zed.txr[a]=pic0.p[y][x].dd>>3; // height = intensity/(2^3)

// compute normals (for OpenGL rendering only)
double n[3],p0[3],px[3],py[3];
int zedx,zedy,picx,picy;
for (a=zed.xs,zedy=-(pic.ys>>1),picy=1;picy<pic.ys;picy++,zedy++)
 for (a++,    zedx=-(pic.xs>>1),picx=1;picx<pic.xs;picx++,zedx++,a++)
    {
    vector_ld(p0,zedx-1,zedy  ,-zed.txr[a       -1]); // 3 neighboring points
    vector_ld(py,zedx  ,zedy-1,-zed.txr[a+zed.xs  ]);
    vector_ld(px,zedx  ,zedy  ,-zed.txr[a         ]);
    vector_sub(px,p0,px); // 2 vectors (latices of quad/triangle)
    vector_sub(py,p0,py);
    vector_mul(n,px,py); // cross product
    vector_one(n,n); // unit vector normalization
    pnx[a]=n[0]; // store vector components to textures
    pny[a]=n[1];
    pnz[a]=n[2];
    }
```

**Here OpenGL preview code (C++):**

```
scr.cls(); // clear buffers

scr.set_perspective(); // set camera matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // set object matrix
rep.use_rep();
glLoadMatrixd(rep.rep);

// directional (normal shading)
float lightAmbient  [4]={0.20,0.20,0.20,1.00};      
float lightDiffuse  [4]={1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00};      
float lightDirection[4]={0.00,0.00,+1.0,0.00};      
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_AMBIENT ,lightAmbient );
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_DIFFUSE ,lightDiffuse );
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1,GL_POSITION,lightDirection);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

// render point cloud
int zedx,zedy,picx,picy,a;
glColor3f(0.7,0.7,0.7);
float *pnx=(float*)nx.txr;
float *pny=(float*)ny.txr;
float *pnz=(float*)nz.txr;
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for (a=zed.xs,zedy=-(pic.ys>>1),picy=1;picy<pic.ys;picy++,zedy++)
 for (a++,    zedx=-(pic.xs>>1),picx=1;picx<pic.xs;picx++,zedx++,a++)
    {
    //glColor4ubv((BYTE*)&pic.p[picy][picx].dd); // this is coloring with original image colors but it hides the 3D effect
    glNormal3f(pnx[a],pny[a],pnz[a]); // normal for lighting
    glVertex3i(zedx  ,zedy  ,-zed.txr[a]); // this is the point cloud surface point coordinate
    }
glEnd();

scr.exe(); // finalize OpenGL calls and swap buffers ...
scr.rfs();
```

**Matrices are set like this:**

```
// gluProjection parameters
double f=100;                   //[pixels] focus
scr.views[0].znear=       f;    //[pixels]
scr.views[0].zfar =1000.0+f;    //[pixels]
scr.views[0].zang =  60.0;      //[deg] view projection angle
scr.init(this); // this compute the Projection matrix and init OpenGL
// place the painting surface in the middle of frustrum
rep.reset();
rep.gpos_set(vector_ld(0.0,0.0,-0.5*(scr.views[0].zfar+scr.views[0].znear)));
rep.lrotx(180.0*deg); // rotate it to match original image
```

**[notes]**

I am using own picture class so here some members:

- `xs,ys` size of image in pixels
- `p[y][x].dd` is pixel at (x,y) position as 32 bit integer type
- `p[y][x].db[4]` is pixel access by color bands (r,g,b,a)

Also I am using custom OpenGl `scr` and Texture Clases:

- `xs,ys` size of buffer in pixels
- `Texture::txr` is 32bit pixel pointer (image is allocated as linear 1D array)
- height map is used to store int values
- normal maps is used to store float normal vector components

The only thing left to do is:

1. filter the pointcloud to your liking
2. triangulate/export to mesh supported by your printer

**There are other ways to encode illumination into surface:**

1. you can do something like **Fresnel lens surface**

   - so divide mesh to segments
   - and offset each so it starts from the same reference plane (z offset)

   That need much less volume/material

   [image: normal height vs. fresnel encoding]

   First half of animation is normal height encoding then it is switched to Fresnel surface encoding/packing for comparison
2. encode illumination not as height map but as **roughness map** instead

   - each pixel will be mapped into small sub height map
   - flat surface is high illumination/intensity  of color
   - rough surface is black
   - and in between are the shades of gray

   This will be visible also from angles and can be relatively thin so need very little material for this (much less then previous bullet)
3. **Real height map** (real 3D mesh representation)

   It is very tricky you need to normalize colors, shadows and illumination artifacts so only normal shading is left (as the surface is from single material,color,shininess,roughness ...) and only then extract the height map. For that you need many things like segmentation, adaptive tresholding, filtering and much more ... At last add the empty inside and add support walls so the mesh holds together while/after printing.

Comment: This program is an implementation of "monocular depth estimation," since it generates a depth map from a single image.