# Augment reality like zookazam

Tags: algorithm, augmented-reality

1. **What algorithms are used for augmented reality like [zookazam](http://www.zookazam.com) ?**

   [image: zookazam example]

   I think it analyze image and find planes by contrast, but i don't know how.
2. **What topics should I read before starting with app like this?**

Comment: added very vague answer (each of the topic can fill whole books) so please be more specific (if you want better answer) have added few things you should add in the prologue section so please read it and update/edit your question.

Comment: here [Если бы вместо Солнца были другие звезды](https://youtu.be/ywvUTWPlBhM) very nice example of augmented reality with complex lighting from one of Moskow webcam swithing the star from Sun to other known stars like Sirius,Vega,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Prologue]**

This is **extremly broad topic** and mostly **off topic** in it's current state. I reedited your question but to make your question answerable within the rules/possibilities of this site

**You should specify more closely what your augmented reality:**

1. **should do**

   - adding **2D/3D** objects with known mesh ...
   - changing light conditions
   - adding/removing body parts/clothes/hairs ...

   a good idea is to provide some example image (sketch) of input/output of what you want to achieve.
2. **what input it has**

   - video,static image, **2D**,stereo,**3D**. For pure **2D** input specify what conditions/markers/illumination/**LASER** patterns you have to help the reconstruction.
   - what will be in the input image? empty room, persons, specific objects etc.
3. **specify target platform**

   many algorithms are limited to memory size/bandwidth, **CPU** power, special **HW** capabilities etc so it is a good idea to add tag for your platform. The **OS** and language is also a good idea to add.

**[How augmented reality works]**

1. **acquire input image**

   if you are connecting to some device like camera you need to use its driver/framework or something to obtain the image or use some common **API** it supports. This task is **OS** dependent.  My favorite way on Windows is to use **VFW** (video for windows) **API**.

   I would start with some static file(s) from start instead to ease up the debug and incremental building process. (you do not need to wait for camera and stuff to happen on each build). And when your App is ready for live video then switch back to camera...
2. **reconstruct the scene into 3D mesh**

   if you use **3D** cameras like **Kinect** then this step is not necessary. Otherwise you need to distinguish the object by some **segmentation** process usually based on the edge detections or color homogenity.

   The quality of the **3D** mesh depends on what you want to achieve and what is your input. For example if you want realistic shadows and lighting then you need very good mesh. If the **camera is fixed** in some **room** you can predefine the mesh manually (hard code it) and compute just the objects in view. Also the objects detection/segmentation can be done very simply by substracting the empty room image from current view image so the pixels with big difference are the objects.

   you can also use planes instead of real 3D mesh as you suggested in the **OP** but then you can forget about more realistic quality of effects like lighting,shadows,intersections... if you assume the objects are standing straight then you can use room metrics to obtain the distance from camera. see:

   - [selection criteria for different projections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32795205/2521214)
   - [estimate measure of photographed things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34085449/2521214)

   For pure **2D** input you can also use the illumination to estimate the **3D** mesh see:

   - [Turn any 2D image into 3D printable sculpture with code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31339320/2521214)
3. **render**

   Just render the scene back to some image/video/screen... with added/removed features. If you are not changing the light conditions too much you can also use the original image and render directly to it. Shadows can be achieved by darkening the pixels ... For better results with this the illumination/shadows/spots/etc. are usually filtered out from the original image and then added directly by rendering instead. see

   - [White balance (Color Suppression) Formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33776667/2521214)
   - [Enhancing dynamic range and normalizing illumination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31558803/2521214)

   The rendering process itself is also platform dependent (unless you are doing it by low level graphics in memory). You can use things like **GDI,DX,OpenGL,...** see:

   - [Graphics rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214)

   You also need camera parameters for rendering like:

   - [Transformation of 3D objects related to vanishing points and horizon line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53303948/2521214)

**[Basic topics to google/read]**

1. **2D**

   - DIP digital image processing
   - Image Segmentation
2. **3D**

   - Vector math
   - [Homogenous coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)
   - 3D scene reconstruction
   - [3D graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100338/2521214)
   - [normal shading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)
3. **paltform dependent**

   - image acquisition
   - rendering