# Silhouette-Outlined shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I'm trying to implement **GLSL** shader which would highlight the outer edges of rendered **3D** mesh. The problem is that I do not have access to the **OpenGL** client side code so this must be done only in **GLSL** shaders.

My first attempt was to use/adopt [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Silhouette-Outlined_Diffuse) shader from **Unity** and do it in **OpenGL GLSL**. Here how it should look:

[image]

And here is what I got:

[image]

I'm not sure If I compute the stuff correctly but as you can see the output is nowhere near my expectations.

Here is the ogre material

```
material Chassis 
    {
    technique
        {    
        pass standard
            {
            cull_software back         
            scene_blend zero one
            }
        pass psssm
            {         
            cull_software front 
            scene_blend src_alpha one_minus_src_alpha         
            vertex_program_ref reflection_cube_specularmap_normalmap_vs100 
                {
                param_named_auto modelViewProjectionMatrix worldviewproj_matrix
                param_named_auto normalMatrix inverse_transpose_world_matrix
                param_named_auto modelView worldview_matrix
                param_named_auto camera_world_position camera_position
                param_named_auto inverse_projection_matrix inverse_projection_matrix
                param_named_auto  projection_matrix projection_matrix
                param_named_auto  p_InverseModelView inverse_worldview_matrix
                }
            fragment_program_ref reflection_cube_specularmap_normalmap_fs100
                {                
                }    
            }
        }
    }
```

**Here is the vertex shader**

```cpp
#version 140
#define lowp
#define mediump
#define highp

in vec4 vertex;
in vec3 normal;   

uniform mat4 normalMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform vec3 camera_world_position;
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 inverse_projection_matrix;
void main()
   {        
   vec4 pos = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vertex;
   mat4 modelView = inverse_projection_matrix * modelViewProjectionMatrix;

   vec4 norm   =   inverse(transpose(modelView)) * vec4(normal, 0.0);
   vec2 offset =   vec2( norm.x * projection_matrix[0][0], norm.y * projection_matrix[1][1] );

   pos.xy += offset * pos.z * 0.18;
   gl_Position = pos;
   }
```

**EDIT**: I have added the material script which ogre uses and I have added the vertex shader code.

Comment: What results to you get? "Strange" isn't very informative! Please make it clearer what your question is.

Comment: ok one second I post a screen shot

Comment: @PeterHall I have added a screenshot

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks for that important notice. I have updated the shader, but still the outlines are missing

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: @genpfault I have modified the post, please for more information do not hesitate to say

Comment: I have edited the post and gave more information

Comment: without knowing what are you passing to the shaders and how are you obtaining outlines  we can only speculate ... Do you just want to emphasize Wireframe or what the object outlines (not the geometry)? what technique are you using? Perhaps multi pass with use of Stencil or render to texture/FBO in first pass for test in second to find edge pixels ? ... I think Fragment shader is more important for this .... Please do not post duplicate answers instead edit your current with more info (and notify user `nick` by comment with `@nick` in it...

Comment: You can do this also without FBO for example render your object without shading with edge color, than render the same object with background color but scaled down a bit (centered around object center) ... All without depth test ...

Comment: @Spektre I was waiting for your answer :). You always solve my problems!!. I want the object outlines not the geometry, the same as the expected picture result that I have shown. but what's wrong with my approach above ? Can you post a corrected approach ?

Comment: @andreahmed I do not see any approach in your code ... it si just Vertex shader passing data to Fragment I do not see code of. I assuming you are passing 3D mesh of the car and do something in the fragment with it... If you want perfect outline (same thickness) then you need 2 pass render. If you want just any outline then the approach from my last comment would suffice. How ever on your desired output image I see too many pixels that are not any outline nor silhouette so to answer we need to know more specifics first... material settings is unimportant for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume single complex **3D** mesh. I would do this with 2 pass rendering:

1. **clear screen**

   let use `(0,0,0)` as clear color.
2. **render mesh**

   disable depth output,test (or clear it afterwards). Do not use shading fill just with some predefined color for example `(1,1,1)` Lets do this for simple cube:

   [image: 1st pass]
3. **read the frame buffer and use it as a texture**

   So either use **FBO** and render to texture for **#1,#2** or use `glReadPixels` instead and load it as some texture back to **GPU** (I know it slower but works also on Intel). For more info see both answers in here:

   - [OpenGL Scale Single Pixel Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654398/2521214)
4. **clear screen with background color**
5. **render**

   so either render `GL_QUAD` covering whole screen or render your mesh with shading and what ever you want. You need to pass also the texture from previous step into **GLSL**.

   In **fragment** render as usual ... but at the end also add this:

   Scan all texels around current fragment screen position up to distance equal to outline thickness in the texture from previous step. If any black pixel found in it override outputted color with your outline color. You can even modulate it with the smallest distance to black color.

   This is very similar to this:

   - [How to implement 2D raycasting light effect in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34708022/2521214)

   but much simpler. Here result:

   [image: 2nd pass]

I took this example [Analysis of a shader in VR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45564968/2521214) of mine and converted it to this:

**Fragment:**

```cpp
// Fragment
#version 400 core
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location : enable
layout(location =64) uniform vec3 lt_pnt_pos;// point light source position [GCS]
layout(location =67) uniform vec3 lt_pnt_col;// point light source color&strength
layout(location =70) uniform vec3 lt_amb_col;// ambient light source color&strength
in vec3 LCS_pos;        // fragment position [LCS]
in vec3 pixel_pos;      // fragment position [GCS]
in vec3 pixel_col;      // fragment surface color
in vec3 pixel_nor;      // fragment surface normal [GCS]
out vec4 col;

// outline
uniform sampler2D txr;  // texture from previous pass
uniform int thickness;  // [pixels] outline thickness
uniform float xs,ys;    // [pixels] texture/screen resolution
void main()
    {
    // standard rendering
    float li;
    vec3 c,lt_dir;
    lt_dir=normalize(lt_pnt_pos-pixel_pos); // vector from fragment to point light source in [GCS]
    li=dot(pixel_nor,lt_dir);
    if (li<0.0) li=0.0;
    c=pixel_col*(lt_amb_col+(lt_pnt_col*li));

    // outline effect
    if (thickness>0)            // thickness effect in second pass
        {
        int i,j,r=thickness;
        float xx,yy,rr,x,y,dx,dy;
        dx=1.0/xs;              // texel size
        dy=1.0/ys;
        x=gl_FragCoord.x*dx;
        y=gl_FragCoord.y*dy;
        rr=thickness*thickness;
        for (yy=y-(float(thickness)*dy),i=-r;i<=r;i++,yy+=dy)
         for (xx=x-(float(thickness)*dx),j=-r;j<=r;j++,xx+=dx)
          if ((i*i)+(j*j)<=rr)
           if ((texture(txr,vec2(xx,yy)).r)<0.01)
            {
            c=vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);    // outline color
            i=r+r+1;
            j=r+r+1;
            break;
            }
        }
    else c=vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);   // render with white in first pass

    // output color
    col=vec4(c,1.0);
    }
```

The **Vertex shader** is without change:

```cpp
// Vertex
#version 400 core
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location : enable
layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 nor;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 col;
layout(location = 0) uniform mat4 m_model;  // model matrix
layout(location =16) uniform mat4 m_normal; // model matrix with origin=(0,0,0)
layout(location =32) uniform mat4 m_view;   // inverse of camera matrix
layout(location =48) uniform mat4 m_proj;   // projection matrix
out vec3 LCS_pos;       // fragment position [LCS]
out vec3 pixel_pos;     // fragment position [GCS]
out vec3 pixel_col;     // fragment surface color
out vec3 pixel_nor;     // fragment surface normal [GCS]

void main()
    {
    LCS_pos=pos;
    pixel_col=col;
    pixel_pos=(m_model*vec4(pos,1)).xyz;
    pixel_nor=(m_normal*vec4(nor,1)).xyz;
    gl_Position=m_proj*m_view*m_model*vec4(pos,1);
    }
```

And **CPU** side code looks like this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "gl_simple.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GLfloat lt_pnt_pos[3]={+2.5,+2.5,+2.5};
GLfloat lt_pnt_col[3]={0.8,0.8,0.8};
GLfloat lt_amb_col[3]={0.2,0.2,0.2};
GLuint txrid=0;
GLfloat animt=0.0;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/46603878/2521214
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    // load values into shader
    GLint i,id;
    GLfloat m[16];
    glUseProgram(prog_id);

    GLfloat x,y,z,d=0.25;

    id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"txr"); glUniform1i(id,0);
    id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"xs"); glUniform1f(id,xs);
    id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"ys"); glUniform1f(id,ys);

    id=64; glUniform3fv(id,1,lt_pnt_pos);
    id=67; glUniform3fv(id,1,lt_pnt_col);
    id=70; glUniform3fv(id,1,lt_amb_col);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,m);
    id=0; glUniformMatrix4fv(id,1,GL_FALSE,m);
    m[12]=0.0; m[13]=0.0; m[14]=0.0;
    id=16; glUniformMatrix4fv(id,1,GL_FALSE,m);
    for (i=0;i<16;i++) m[i]=0.0; m[0]=1.0; m[5]=1.0; m[10]=1.0; m[15]=1.0;
    id=32; glUniformMatrix4fv(id,1,GL_FALSE,m);
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,m);
    id=48; glUniformMatrix4fv(id,1,GL_FALSE,m);


    // draw VAO cube (no outline)
    id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"thickness"); glUniform1i(id,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    vao_draw(); // render cube

    // copy frame buffer to CPU memory and than back to GPU as Texture
    BYTE *map=new BYTE[xs*ys*4];
    glReadPixels(0,0,xs,ys,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,map);    // framebuffer -> map[]
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,txrid);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, xs, ys, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, map); // map[] -> texture txrid
    delete[] map;

    // draw VAO cube (outline)
    id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"thickness"); glUniform1i(id,5);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    vao_draw(); // render cube
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // turn of shader
    glUseProgram(0);

    // rotate the cube to see animation
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
//  glRotatef(1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
//  glRotatef(1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    gl_init(Handle);

    glGenTextures(1,&txrid);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,txrid);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_COPY);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    int hnd,siz; char vertex[4096],fragment[4096];
    hnd=FileOpen("normal_shading.glsl_vert",fmOpenRead); siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2); FileSeek(hnd,0,0); FileRead(hnd,vertex  ,siz); vertex  [siz]=0; FileClose(hnd);
    hnd=FileOpen("normal_shading.glsl_frag",fmOpenRead); siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2); FileSeek(hnd,0,0); FileRead(hnd,fragment,siz); fragment[siz]=0; FileClose(hnd);
    glsl_init(vertex,fragment);
//  hnd=FileCreate("GLSL.txt"); FileWrite(hnd,glsl_log,glsl_logs); FileClose(hnd);

    int i0,i;
    mm_log->Lines->Clear();
    for (i=i0=0;i<glsl_logs;i++)
     if ((glsl_log[i]==13)||(glsl_log[i]==10))
        {
        glsl_log[i]=0;
        mm_log->Lines->Add(glsl_log+i0);
        glsl_log[i]=13;
        for (;((glsl_log[i]==13)||(glsl_log[i]==10))&&(i<glsl_logs);i++);
        i0=i;
        }
    if (i0<glsl_logs) mm_log->Lines->Add(glsl_log+i0);

    vao_init();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    glDeleteTextures(1,&txrid);
    gl_exit();
    glsl_exit();
    vao_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight-mm_log->Height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glTranslatef(0,0,-15.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glRotatef(-15.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(-125.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    animt+=0.02; if (animt>1.5) animt=-0.5;
    Caption=animt;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseWheel(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
    {
    GLfloat dz=2.0;
    if (WheelDelta<0) dz=-dz;
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glTranslatef(0,0,dz);
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As usual the code is using/based on this:

- [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

**[Notes]**

In case you got multiple objects then use for each object different color in **#2**. Then in **#5** scan for any different color then the one that is in the texel at current position instead of scanning  for black.

Also this can be done on 2D image instead of using mesh. You just need to know the background color. So you can use pre-renderd/grabed/screenshoted images for this too.

You can add `discard`  and or change the final `if` logic to change behaviour (like you want just outline and no mesh inside etc ...). Or you can add the outline color to render color instead of assigning it directly to get the impression of highlight ... instead of coloring

[image: options]

see a),b),c) options in modified fragment:

```cpp
// Fragment
#version 400 core
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location : enable
layout(location =64) uniform vec3 lt_pnt_pos;// point light source position [GCS]
layout(location =67) uniform vec3 lt_pnt_col;// point light source color&strength
layout(location =70) uniform vec3 lt_amb_col;// ambient light source color&strength
in vec3 LCS_pos;        // fragment position [LCS]
in vec3 pixel_pos;      // fragment position [GCS]
in vec3 pixel_col;      // fragment surface color
in vec3 pixel_nor;      // fragment surface normal [GCS]
out vec4 col;

// outline
uniform sampler2D txr;  // texture from previous pass
uniform int thickness;  // [pixels] outline thickness
uniform float xs,ys;    // [pixels] texture/screen resolution
void main()
    {
    // standard rendering
    float li;
    vec3 c,lt_dir;
    lt_dir=normalize(lt_pnt_pos-pixel_pos); // vector from fragment to point light source in [GCS]
    li=dot(pixel_nor,lt_dir);
    if (li<0.0) li=0.0;
    c=pixel_col*(lt_amb_col+(lt_pnt_col*li));

    // outline effect
    if (thickness>0)            // thickness effect in second pass
        {
        int i,j,r=thickness;
        float xx,yy,rr,x,y,dx,dy;
        dx=1.0/xs;              // texel size
        dy=1.0/ys;
        x=gl_FragCoord.x*dx;
        y=gl_FragCoord.y*dy;
        rr=thickness*thickness;
        for (yy=y-(float(thickness)*dy),i=-r;i<=r;i++,yy+=dy)
         for (xx=x-(float(thickness)*dx),j=-r;j<=r;j++,xx+=dx)
          if ((i*i)+(j*j)<=rr)
           if ((texture(txr,vec2(xx,yy)).r)<0.01)
            {
            c =vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);   // a) assign outline color
//          c+=vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);   // b) add outline color
            i=r+r+1;
            j=r+r+1;
            r=0;
            break;
            }
//      if (r!=0) discard; // c) do not render inside
        }
    else c=vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);   // render with white in first pass

    // output color
    col=vec4(c,1.0);
    }
```

**[Edit1] single pass approach for smooth edges**

As you can not access client side code this approach will work in shader only. For smooth (curved) edged shapes the surface normal is near perpendicular to camera view axis (`z`). So `dot` between them is near zero. This can be exploited directly ... Here update of the shaders:

**Vertex**

```cpp
// Vertex
#version 400 core
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location : enable
layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 nor;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 col;
layout(location = 0) uniform mat4 m_model;  // model matrix
layout(location =16) uniform mat4 m_normal; // model matrix with origin=(0,0,0)
layout(location =32) uniform mat4 m_view;   // inverse of camera matrix
layout(location =48) uniform mat4 m_proj;   // projection matrix
out vec3 pixel_pos;     // fragment position [GCS]
out vec3 pixel_col;     // fragment surface color
out vec3 pixel_nor;     // fragment surface normal [GCS]
out vec3 view_nor;     // surface normal in camera [LCS]

void main()
    {
    pixel_col=col;
    pixel_pos=(m_model*vec4(pos,1)).xyz;
    pixel_nor=(m_normal*vec4(nor,1)).xyz;

    mat4 m;
    m=m_model*m_view;                   // model view matrix
    m[3].xyz=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);         // with origin set to (0,0,0)
    view_nor=(m*vec4(nor,1.0)).xyz;     // object local normal to camera local normal

    gl_Position=m_proj*m_view*m_model*vec4(pos,1);
    }
```

**Fragment**

```cpp
// Fragment
#version 400 core
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location : enable
layout(location =64) uniform vec3 lt_pnt_pos;// point light source position [GCS]
layout(location =67) uniform vec3 lt_pnt_col;// point light source color&strength
layout(location =70) uniform vec3 lt_amb_col;// ambient light source color&strength
in vec3 pixel_pos;      // fragment position [GCS]
in vec3 pixel_col;      // fragment surface color
in vec3 pixel_nor;      // fragment surface normal [GCS]
out vec4 col;

// outline
in vec3 view_nor;     // surface normal in camera [LCS]

void main()
    {
    // standard rendering
    float li;
    vec3 c,lt_dir;
    lt_dir=normalize(lt_pnt_pos-pixel_pos); // vector from fragment to point light source in [GCS]
    li=dot(pixel_nor,lt_dir);
    if (li<0.0) li=0.0;
    c=pixel_col*(lt_amb_col+(lt_pnt_col*li));

    // outline effect
    if (abs(dot(view_nor,vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0)))<=0.5) c=vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);

    // output color
    col=vec4(c,1.0);
    }
```

Here preview:

[image: preview]

As you can see it works properly for smooth objects but for sharp edges like on cube is this not working at all... You can use the same combinations (`a,b,c`) as in previous approach.

The `m` holds modelview matrix with origin set to `(0,0,0)`. That enables it for vector conversion (no translation). For more info see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214).

The `0.5` in the dot product result `if` is the thickness of outline. `0.0` means no outline and `1.0` means whole object is outline.

Comment: The problem with this approach is I just need to do it in shader.. I don't have access to client code. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: That is a problem as you can not both read and write the same buffer in GLSL at the same time ... if you can pass previous frame as texture then this is doable but I see no way to do this without client side pgm change

Comment: But why it works in unity cg, do you want the reference shader that I copied

Comment: @andreahmed I do not use unity but if Unity has some function that does it it most likely do it like the approach I described (as they do have access to client code).

Comment: They just assign the material without any client code. But what I see is they are using a render queue tag, how would I do the same in glsl

Comment: @andreahmed You cant as that is not done in shader side... The unity is rendering engine and it uses its own custom code on client side of OpenGL. If you do not have access to client side code you simply cant do this. There might be work arrounds however using hacking into target application stealing its gfx output and use it in different application that will present the output...

Comment: @andreahmed added code and few related links for this and 3 options to modify the result rendering output style. Now you can tweak it to whatever you need to

Comment: @andreahmed btw just occur to me if your mesh is complete smooth curved solid surface the edges normals in screen space would be near to perpendicular to z axis. So you could explot that in fragment shader in single pass without any client side code change. Just throw away any fragments with normal not near perpendicular to Z axis of camera. for example `if (dot(frag_normal,camera_z_axis)>0.1) discard; else col=vec4(1.0,0.0,.0.0,.0.0);`   but that would not work for non smoothly curved objects like cube ... Any sharp edge will not be rendered properly

Comment: How would I compute fragment normal. Btw thanks so much

Comment: @andreahmed You would not you should already got it as without normals you can not do any lighting... So the client is most likely 99.999% passing them from the mesh directly as some layout. I think `in vec3 normal;` is it. So in fragment shader try: `if (abs(dot(norm,vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0)))>0.1) discard; else col=vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);`

Comment: but with the last approach I have to do two passes and do software culling front and back ? and scene blend zero one

Comment: @andreahmed no You just add that single line to fragment shader ... If you have the approach from the last comment in mind.

Comment: how would I transform normals from view space into projected space. If you see unity function transfromviewprojection they are using the projection matrix with normals

Comment: @andreahmed you can use any coordinate system you want , the only thing is that both vectors in the dot product must be in the same coordinate system. To answer your question I would need to know what your matrices are ... I suspect something like `norm = (modelView*vec4(normal,1.0)).xyz-camera_world_position;` for more info see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

Comment: a cheap way to do this is to add a second object with the same mesh and solid color and invert the scale. i dont know much about the engine he's using but it should work.