# What are the highlights that all these games suddenly have?

Tags: graphics

I was casually gaming when I see all of these games suddenly having the exact same "Highlighting", that is weirdly smooth and kind of pleasurable to my eye

Ravenfield:

[image: img]

Roblox:

[image: img]

Lego DC Supervillian:

[image: img]

The first place I tried looking was google with just "highlight" "all games have the same thing" "all games have the same highlight" but I think because my brain is stuck with the word "highlight" that I cant think of any other words to search, I also looked in opengl (though I couldnt find any working links to docs or updates there) however when I first saw it I thought that it might haved worked by having multiple viewports ontop of eachother

**tl;dr im seeing the exact same special effect in most of the games I play and would like to know its basic implementation or how it works**

Comment: You simply render the selected object with different color (or no lighting) and or with blending and or without depth test ... if you mean the outline that is doable by morphological DIP operators also see [Analysis of a shader in VR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45564968/2521214) and [Silhouette-Outlined shader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46618346/2521214)

Comment: Yes also thanks for adding the images I didn't have enough rep for them