# Easy way to calculate surface normals on image?

Tags: math, graphics, computer-vision, geometry-surface

Is there an easy way to calculate the surface normal on a 2d jpg or png image?  If so how is this possible could someone write out some pseudo code and explain for me?  I have been reading online but haven't found anything that makes sense yet.  This isn't a depth image it is simply a jpg of anything.

Edit: or is there anything in openCV or anywhere that can automatically do this for you?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking.  But even if you do clarify what you mean, "how do I" questions are generally too broad for SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn any 2D image into 3D printable sculpture with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322052/turn-any-2d-image-into-3d-printable-sculpture-with-code)

Comment: see [Turn any 2D image into 3D printable sculpture with code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31339320/2521214) for some simple basics

Comment: im looking at this paper http://www.cosy.sbg.ac.at/~uhl/mmsec/acm05.pdf and they are claiming you need to calculate the surface normal at the point (x, y).  I want to do the 2d implementation.