# Possible to generate a cad file from a picture of an object and specifying a reference distance?

Tags: ios, graphics, augmented-reality, cad, dxf

Ok, I am attempting to deconstruct or reverse engineer an object made out of Plexi. The problem I'm running into is that my calipers are not long enough. SO... Is it possible, given an object, and a known distance on a perspective plane, to be able to precisely generate measurements?

I would like to recreate the object to make modifications at a place the mills Plexi, and not destroy my only piece.

Thanks in advance!

The following is an image of the back panel:

[image: back panel]

Comment: forget about precise in image measurements... I think much simpler would be to use 3D scanner (any decend 3D printer company has at least one) but the precision is also dependent on the surface and shape of the part itself. The usual stereoscopy/3D reconstruction from motion/Kinect scanners are not much precise so you will  end up with approx shape and need to tweak resulting mesh to real dimensions in some 3D editing tool. UltraSonic phase array scanners will get you the best mesh but they are rare and expensive (I saw only one).

Comment: For your question see these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34085449/2521214 ,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32795205/2521214 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/53303948/2521214 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/31339320/2521214. btw why [augmented reality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35752786/2521214) tag? 3D reconstruction is more `[CV]` related

Comment: can you add image(s) so we see what exactly you dealing with ...

Comment: @Spektre, my object is nowhere as advanced as a picture of Michelle Pfeiffe . It's the back panel of a plexi computer case. I was hoping to do some kind of (as simple and fast as possible) image processing, in order to get dimensions close to 0.01 precision as possible.

Comment: @Spektre, I used the AR-tag because A LOT of measuring tools for iPad or iPhone, references AR. So just like a sheeple, I thought this was the way to go.

Comment: AR is a huge topic covering a lot of different things... I think what you want to focus on is 3D reconstruction .... hmm added image shows a planar object ... that should be doable quite easily just using [birdseye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39316776/2521214) transformation ... simply take a photo from not very close distance (to limit fisheye distortions) and as straight as you can with some square marker , then apply transformation of markers into real square and you can measure pixels directly... or vectorize ... IIRC OpenCV had some functions to do this

Comment: @Spektre actually, I just need the dimensions of the flat plane. I want to make some modifications and need to do it quickly. Can you suggest (of course, I will not hold any liability) of something that can take, say that image or others, use a “story pole” to get some kind of vector/distance and extrapolate close to exact measurements, say in metric or imperial?